# Logging into SuperUser via mobile phone

Tags: support, login, mobile

I try to log into SuperUser from my mobile phone, but it fails. I can easily browse the pages of SuperUser, but when I click on "login" and then select my OpenID account provider, it doesn't work. Is it because of the phone? My mobile phone is Samsung C5212.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13002/im-not-human-if-im-using-my-mobile,

Comment: I haven't noticed it ChrisF, but my phone supports Java scripts and I can see the OpenID links.

Comment: What mobile browser are you using?

Comment: When I open the browser, a splash screen comes saying "Access Powered". I think it's a standard browser for Samsung phones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I am not sure what OS this phone is running.

http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_c5212_duos_preview-review-322p3.php

However, you need a fairly advanced mobile web browser to use SO. I know that Windows Mobile 6+, iPhone (all versions), Android (all versions) work OK.

Comment: Ok(ish), not great though. Nudge nudge, wink wink...

Comment: it's amazing that it works AT ALL, since we never targetted mobile with our site. We always wanted to be fast and efficient, but on a desktop or laptop. This says more about how fast mobile browsers are improving than us, but it is the future -- blurring lines between mobile and computers ... well, small-screen, netbook style computers at least.

Comment: I didn't say it was bad, the interface on mobile phones is surprisingly usable. But it could be so much better! At the very least, create an API so others can create apps that allow us to have a better mobile experience (I'm looking at iPhone OS and Android in particular). A lot of people want that.